# How to use position_jitter_tern() in ggtern() in R?

Tags: r, ggtern

I am creating a simple ternary plot.

```
ggtern(data=data.frame(x=c(0.1,0.1),y=c(0.2,0.2),z=c(0.7,0.7)),aes(x,y,z)) + geom_point()
```

How can I jitter the point so that the plot will display two points?
I tried using position_jitter_tern like so: but it isn't changing anything.

```
ggtern(data=data.frame(x=c(0.1,0.1),y=c(0.2,0.2),z=c(0.7,0.7)),aes(x,y,z, position_jitter_tern(0.1,0.1,0.1))) + geom_point()
```

[Image can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RFhp.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "position" option inside the `geom_point` function.

```
library(ggtern)

df <- data.frame(x=c(0.1,0.1),y=c(0.2,0.2),z=c(0.7,0.7))

ggtern(data=df, aes(x,y,z) ) + 
       geom_point(position= position_jitter_tern(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=0.02))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply base `jitter` function to the dataframe.

```
library(ggtern)
library(ggplot2)

data=data.frame(x=c(0.1,0.1),y=c(0.2,0.2),z=c(0.7,0.7))
data[] <- lapply(data, jitter, 3)
ggtern(data,aes(x,y,z)) + geom_point()
```

[image]